# UITableView in UIView in UIScrollView , I can't scroll up the tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, scroll, height

I add a UITableView to a UIView and then add the UIView to the UIScrollView , then according to the contentOffset of the scrollview to change the height of the table ,then I can't scroll up to see the content below the UITableView!

Comment: `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, your setup doesn't seem like the best approach.

Comment: I want to scroll the view outside of the UITableView up and down, so I add the UIView on UIScrollView, if it's not the approach, then will you put some key codes? Thanks

Comment: Add all your views as custom table cells or header/footer views.

Comment: In my scrollview I want to add 3 views, 2 UITableView and a uicollectionview so how can I mitigate these 3 views into a UITableView? Then I can use headerview and section view to escape from scroll conflicts ! thanks !

Comment: Maybe this can be useful: https://github.com/zwaldowski/AAPLAdvancedCollectionView